# Show that $\det(A-\lambda I)=\det(B-\lambda I)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Alright, I've been trying to work this linear algebra problem out for a bit and I don't seem to be getting anywhere. The problem is this:

Assume that $A=M^{-1}BM$. Show that $\det(A-\lambda I)=\det(B-\lambda I)$.

So my instincts tell me that this has something to do with the fact that $A^n$ can be expressed as $M^{-1}BM$

Comment: This rather has something to do with the fact that det(UV)=det(U)det(V) for suitable matrices U and V...

Comment: Hint: $\lambda I = M^{-1}(\lambda I) M$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A small hint: In the expression $\det(A-\lambda I)$ you can use the given fact that $A=M^{-1}BM$ of course, but also that $I=M^{-1}IM$.

Comment: BAH! That was simple. I should not be doing these things at midnight. Thank you so much, problem solved.

Comment: @Colin: You're welcome.

Comment: @Colin: If you're happy with Hans's answer, please remember to click the checkmark to the left of his answer, so that the software considers this resolved. :)